# How to calculate meal break start time in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate meal break start time based on shift length for the following sample data.

[image: Data]

Business rules to calculate, "Where the shift length is > 6 hours,  insert meal break start time in column F.  Meal break start time must be  5 hours from the shift start time in column C"

I have applied below formula to derive the output;

=C27+TIME(5,0,0)

I am not sure if this is correct.

Could you pls suggest how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

That looks good! Now you just need a check for the shift length, so it doesn't show a meal break start time if the shift isn't long enough.

```
=IF(E27>TIME(6,0,0), C27+TIME(5,0,0), "")
```